# Proof of SAT is randomly reducible to UNIQUE-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, proof-techniques

I am asking for help to explain some crucial points of the central lemma and it's proof of famous paper [NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions by L.Valiant and V.Vazirani](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/NP_is_as.pdf).

The proof can be found in the section **2. The proof** of the paper.

**The idea of the lemma**: lemma shows that there is a randomized polynomial - time reduction from SAT to Unique-SAT. Lemma uses GF[2] inner product with polynomial few {0,1} vectors.

**Problem in general**: I have some difficulties in understanding the definition of the lemma and in usage of GF[2] for proving the lemma.

**Specific questions:**

Following is the number of citations from the paper with relevant question to the citation.

> **Lemma 2.1.** If $f$ is any CNF formula in $x_1,...,x_n$ and $w_1,...,w_k \in \{0,1\}^n$,

Q:I think $x_1,...,x_n$ are literals, but what are $w_1,..,w_k$? Are they literals or something else? If yes, why to distinct between them and $x$ literals.

A:$w_1,..,w_k$ are the truth assignments.

> then one can construct in linear time a formula $f'_k$ whose solution $v$ satisfy $f$ and the equations $v\cdot  w_1=...=v\cdot w_k=0$. Furthermore, one can construt a polynomial-size CNF formula $f_k$ in variables $x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...y_m$,

Q: $x_1,...x_n$ are unknown literals, how can we construct $f_k$ with unknown literals and where $y_1,...,y_m$ came from?

> for some $m$ such that there is a bijection between solutions of $f_k$ and $f'_k$, defined be equality on the $x_1,...,x_n$ values.
>
> **Proof**: It is sufficient to show the lemma for $k=1$. Then, $f'_k$ is
>
> $f \wedge (x_{i_1} \bigoplus x_{i_2} \bigoplus ... \bigoplus x_{i_j} \bigoplus 1)$

Q: this is the most vague point, how do we come to the such construction of $f'_1$ and why showing only $f'_1$ sufficient for the proof.

I hope you forgive me for my naivety. I will appreciate any hint in accordance to the above questions.

Comment: You are confusing truth assignments and literals, and you are also confusing vectors and their components.  I suggest that you read what is written in the paper more carefully.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, thank you very much for the comment, I've added some answers, $w_1,...,w_k$ are truth assignments, however the entire idea of the prof is still vague.

Answer (score 4):

> Q: $x_1,...x_n$ are unknown literals, how can we construct $f_k$ with unknown literals and where $y_1,...,y_m$ came from?

$x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are *variables*, each of which can appear as a positive literal ($x_i$) or a negative one ($\lnot x_i$). To construct an equivalent formula $f_1$ of another formula $f_1'$, you don't have to know the values (truth assignments) of $f_1'$. (A simple example is $x_1 \to x_2 \Leftrightarrow \lnot x_1 \lor x_2$.)

The variables $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ are unimportant (at least in this Lemma). The Lemma define the "equivalence" of the two formulas $f_1$ and $f_1'$ by equality on the $x_i$ values (leaving $y_i$ values unspecified).

---

> Q: How do we come to the such construction of $f'_1$ and why showing only $f'_1$ sufficient for the proof?

Each $f_i$ (and $f_i'$) is independent and similar. Therefore, the case of $f_1'$ is sufficient for the proof. To justify the construction of $f_1' = f \land (x_{i_1} \oplus x_{i_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{i_j} \oplus 1)$, you should prove the following two points:

- Each solution $v$ to $f_1'$ satisfies $f$.

This is trivial by the definition of $f_1'$.

- Each solution $v$ satisfies the equation $v \cdot w_1 = 0$.

This is the tricky part. We argue as follows:

First, $$v \cdot w_1 = x_{i_1} + x_{i_2} + \cdots + x_{i_j} \text{ (here `+` is over GF[2])} = x_{i_1} \oplus x_{i_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{i_j}$$ 
The first equality follows from the fact that other $w_l$ with indices $l \neq i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_j$ are all 0 (according to the definition of all $x_{i_j}$).

Because $v$ is a solution to $f_1'$, we have $$x_{i_1} \oplus x_{i_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{i_j} \oplus 1 = 1$$
Thus,
$$v \cdot w_1 = x_{i_1} \oplus x_{i_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus x_{i_j} = 0$$